# Imagemagick Colorspace Black/White to CMYK

Tags: imagemagick, cmyk, imagemagick-convert, mogrify

I have to batch convert a whole directory from colorspace Black/White (shown in XNView) to CMYK for print..

I tried like this (worked well for "normal" graphics..)

```
mogrify.exe  -path [...]\Logos -profile [...]\RGB\AdobeRGB1998.icc  [...]\Logos\*


mogrify.exe -path [...]\Logos  -profile [...]\CMYK\CoatedFOGRA39.icc [...]\Logos\*
```

[...] usually contains a specific path..

whats wrong here? After the procedure the files are much bigger 20kb compared to 400kb.. But they are still colorspace black/white...

Anyone an idea?

Comment: how do you check the colorspace of the images? Gimp?

Comment: XNView... Photoshop says the same..

Answer (score 1):

If the files are truly in the grayscale colorspace then they do not need to be converted to CMYK. CMYK files are larger than RGB files because there are four channels in CMYK and only three in RGB. You may also find that if you convert RGB blacks to CMYK blacks then you no longer have BLACK. You will get strange values such as C 78 M 84 Y 97 K 89.